# e.namedvalues is not defined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

e.namedvalues is not defined.
when aform submited to google sheet, create a doc file in a specific template and then covert the file to PDF and then attach the file to email and then send email to the applicant.
the bellow code creates the file, covert it to PDF and store both of them on google drive specific folder, but the last formula, "send email", is not working.
erro massage is (namedvalues is not defiend).
can any one help me in this regard.

```
function afterformsubmit (e){
  const info = e.namedvalues;
  const pdfFile = createPDF (info);
sendEmail(e.namedvalues['Email Address'],pdfFile);
}
function sendEmail(email,pdfFile) {
GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "here is your file", "please process it",{
  attachement: [pdfFile],
  name: 'transportfile'
})
  
}
function createPDF() {
  const info = {


    'Date of request' : ['7/26/2022'],
    'From' : ['Wardak'],
    'Going To' : ['Said Abad'],
    'Office' : ['WRMO'],
    'Unit' : ['M&E'],
    'Date of visit' : ['7/26/2022'],
    'Time of Visit' : ['12:00:00 PM'],
    'Passenger name' : ['Adil mansour'],    
    'Contact add' : ['0456125421'],
    'Pick up location' : ['Said Abad'],
    'Return date' : ['7/26/2022'],
    'Return time' : ['8:00:00 AM'],
    'Number of Passenger' : ['Kabul'],
    'Return Pick up' : ['Kabul'],
    'emailadd': ['Email Address'],

  }
const PDFfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1DOuJV6BDvsHj1kuYIXuV_gvhz7fIogYs");
const tempfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1RYqxPdGoUPftkemxAktGFhLiZF6EiJDI");
const templatedoc = DriveApp.getFileById("1lXxmwzAilKLUQSkJ7TOe-O0Y149xP_3Bx_YQu7hwd6w");

const newTempfile = templatedoc.makeCopy(tempfolder);
const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempfile.getId());
const body = openDoc.getBody();
body.replaceText("{dor}", info['Date of request'][0]);
body.replaceText("{from}", info['From'][0]);
body.replaceText("{to}", info['Going To'][0]);
body.replaceText("{Office}", info['Office'][0]);
body.replaceText("{Unit}", info['Unit'][0]);
body.replaceText("{dov}", info['Date of visit'][0]);
body.replaceText("{tov}", info['Time of Visit'][0]);
body.replaceText("{Passenger name}", info['Passenger name'][0]);
body.replaceText("{Contact add}", info['Contact add'][0]);
body.replaceText("{Pick up location}", info['Pick up location'][0]);
body.replaceText("{Return date}", info['Return date'][0]);
body.replaceText("{Return time}", info['Return time'][0]);
body.replaceText("{Number of Passenger}", info['Number of Passenger'][0]);
body.replaceText("{Return location}", info['Return Pick up'][0]);
openDoc.saveAndClose();


const bolbPDF = newTempfile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);

const pdfFile = PDFfolder.createFile(bolbPDF).setName("My PDF");
```

Comment: I think that `namedvalues` is required to be modified. Please modify `e.namedvalues` to `e.namedValues` as the camel case. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: Tanaike's answer is spot on. In the future just do a `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e, null, 2))` to see exactly what you are receiving in the event, then you can spot the typos more easily.